# progress bar that has two label on left and right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar, text-alignment

I want to make a progress bar like this

[image]

but i always encounter problem with the alignment, this is my recent output.

[image]

im supposed to use `.progress-label` but i dont know how to incorporate it with the progress bar without messing up the alignment. also i want that blurry text effect on that "signals" text.

Comment: What do you have so far? post a jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hae95z1j/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/hae95z1j/2/

```
           <p class="pull-left media-name">FACEBOOK</p>

        <div>
            <span class="progress-label">9 signals</span>
            <span class="pull-right">60%</span>

        <div class="progress">

            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:60%"></div>
        </div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**To add progress bar having labels in left and right in kendo UI.**

- Left Label :- Less Likely
- Right Label:- Likely

  $("#lesslikely").remove();

  ```
              var progressdata=$("#progressbar").data("kendoProgressBar");
              progressdata.progressStatus.text("<span style='float:right;'>Likely</span>");
  ```

  var wrapper=$(".k-progress-status-wrap").html();

  ```
          wrapper=wrapper+'<span id="lesslikely" style="float:left;margin-left:5px;">Less Likely</span>';
          wrapper=wrapper.replace(/&lt;/g,'<').replace(/&gt;/g,'>').replace(/&amp;/g,'&');
          $(".k-progress-status-wrap").html(wrapper);
  ```